# ubuntu 16 cannot install robomongo

Tags: qt, ubuntu, robo3t

I am getting error when installing robomongo,I am new to ubuntu and i have checked and all qt files are present there.Still i am getting the error

```
  /robomongo
./robomongo: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.7' not found (required by ./robomongo)
./robomongo: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by ./robomongo)
./robomongo: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by ./robomongo)
./robomongo: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by ./robomongo)
```

[image]

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Comment: yeah, i copied tar file to the location and extracted it ,this solved my issue I think earlier, while copying it as folder some files has gone missing.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please clarify your question are you trying to install Robomongo from installer file or are you trying to build Robomongo from source code?

If you try to build, please follow steps in Robomongo github wiki how to build for MAC/Linux document. (I am one of the developers of Robomongo)